# Loading failed for web-animations.min.js

Tags: angular, angular-material, web-animations

I have used Pagination in a part of my page form [this site](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview). I follow its instruction and now bellow are my related files in project:

**app.item.html**

```
<mat-paginator [length]="100"
               [pageSize]="10"
               [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
</mat-paginator>
```

**app.item.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';



@Component({

  templateUrl: './app.item-list.html',
  styleUrls: ['table-pagination-example.css']

})

export class ItemListComponent {

}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "art-shop",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "0.0.46",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "^5.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.4",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~9.3.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "npm-update-all": "^1.0.1",
    "protractor": "~5.2.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    headerComponent,
    footerComponent,
    registerSellerComponent,
    ProductListComponent,
    ItemListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

I installed `web-animations` with this command : `npm install --save web-animations-js`

and put `<script src="../node_modules/web-animations-js/web-animations.min.js"></script>` in my `index.html` and uncommented

```
import 'web-animations-js'
```

in my `polyfill.ts` but not only the pagination does not work and is like that but also I see this error in my browser :

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:4200/node_modules/web-animations-js/web-animations.min.js”.
```

Comment: By the way, you should follow the style guide and make the first letter of your component's name in caps: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-02-03

Comment: Did you include a theme?

Comment: yes I use a theme.@Edric

Answer (score 1):

You don't **have to** include a `script` tag for `web-animations-js`. It should already be handled by `polyfills.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

node_modules is not deployed with your app.

In index.html, replace the URL with a CDN to the web-animations library:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web-animations/2.3.1/web-animations.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: my application is to run on a system without access to the Internet. so I can not use CDN.@pixelbits